# Wordpress (on Rackspace Server) force the entire site over SSL except one page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have a Wordpress site on a Rackspace Cloud Sites server and I currently have both the url and admin url set to the `https` version of the site.  In addition, I have the following code setup in the `htaccess` file to direct all pages to be over `https`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Force SSL on entire site
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code works but now I need one page (`/example-page`) to redirect to the `http` url because we have to include embed code from a third party that does not have an `https` version of the site.  I tried the following code but it just redirects to the home page of the site.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/example-page\/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/example-page\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/example-page\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/example-page\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that the main Wordpress URL setting is set to `https`.  I appreciate any help you can give me.

Panama Jack, This is my full htaccess file after trying what you suggested.  I get an endless loop error for the entire site.  The middle bottom of this document are all the redirects we had to setup for old pages to direct to the new pages, just fyi.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Force SSL on entire site
#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^((?!bill-tracker/?$).*)$ https://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^(bill-tracker/?)$ http://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]


#Redirect Specific Pages
RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1477-2015-florida-minimum-wage-announced https://www.frla.org/news-release/frla-endorses-governor-rick-scott-for-november-2014-election/

RedirectMatch 301 /membership/membership-directory/map https://www.frla.org/member-directory/

RedirectMatch 301 /calendar/flat https://www.frla.org/events/

RedirectMatch 301 /membership-form https://www.frla.org/membership/join

RedirectMatch 301 /about/4-training-certification https://www.frla.org/government-relations

Redirect 301 /faq https://www.frla.org/about/faqs

Redirect 301 /endless-summer-music-series-and-events https://www.frla.org/endless-summer-music-series-events/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/551-tip-outs-and-tip-pooling https://www.frla.org/news-release/tip-outs-and-tip-pooling

RedirectMatch 301 /about/item/127-ceo-profile-carol-dover https://www.frla.org/leadership/

RedirectMatch 301 /educational-foundation/item/198-prostart-school-to-career-program https://www.frla.org/educational-foundation/prostart/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1491-chef-emeril-lagasse-highlights-special-occasion-restaurants-in-florida-on-national-tv https://www.frla.org/news-release/chef-emeril-lagasse-highlights-special-occasion-restaurants-in-florida-on-national-tv-2/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1501-hundreds-of-florida-high-school-students-showcase-culinary-arts-and-restaurant-management-skills-at-statewide-competition https://www.frla.org/news-release/hundreds-of-florida-high-school-students-showcase-culinary-arts-and-restaurant-management-skills-at-statewide-competition/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1502-chef-emeril-lagasse-tours-downtown-restaurants-in-the-sunshine-state-on-latest-episode-of-emerils-florida https://www.frla.org/news-release/chef-emeril-lagasse-tours-downtown-restaurants-in-the-sunshine-state-on-latest-episode-of-emerils-florida-2/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1500-frlas-broward-chapter-raises-funds-to-support-hospitality-education-for-local-high-school-students https://www.frla.org/frla-news/item/1500-frlas-broward-chapter-raises-funds-to-support-hospitality-education-for-local-high-school-students

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1498-florida-restaurant-and-lodging-associations-pinellas-chapter-installs-new-officers-and-board-of-directors-for-2015 https://www.frla.org/news-release/64863/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1503-panama-city-beach-businesses-community-leaders-and-law-enforcement-prepare-for-safe-and-successful-spring-break-at-hospitality-workshop https://www.frla.org/news-release/panama-city-beach-businesses-community-leaders-and-law-enforcement-prepare-for-safe-and-successful-spring-break-at-hospitality-workshop-2/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1505-rep-harrison-and-sen-abruzzo-file-bill-to-spur-economic-development https://www.frla.org/news-release/rep-harrison-and-sen-abruzzo-file-bill-to-spur-economic-development/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1410-chef-emeril-lagasse-visits-central-florida-farm-to-table-restaurant-and-egg-farm-in-latest-emerils-florida-television-episode- https://www.frla.org/news-release/chef-emeril-lagasse-visits-central-florida-farm-to-table-restaurant-and-egg-farm-in-latest-emerils-florida-television-episode/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1420-chef-emeril-lagasse-samples-restaurants-in-south-walton-county-on-latest-emerils-florida-tv-episode https://www.frla.org/news-release/chef-emeril-lagasse-samples-restaurants-in-south-walton-county-on-latest-emerils-florida-tv-episode/

RedirectMatch 301 /images/2014_Florida_Tourism_Day_Registration_Form.pdf https://www.frla.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/2014_Florida_Tourism_Day_Registration_Form.pdf

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1433-gov-scott-another-record-year-for-florida-tourism https://www.frla.org/news-release/gov-scott-another-record-year-for-florida-tourism/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1434-frla-members-donate-reusable-inventory-to-the-florida-department-of-corrections https://www.frla.org/news-release/frla-members-donate-reusable-inventory-to-the-florida-department-of-corrections/

RedirectMatch 301 /images/stories/GR/FRLA_2014_Legislative_Scorecard.pdf https://www.frla.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/FRLA_2014_Legislative_Scorecard.pdf

RedirectMatch 301 /events/board-meetings https://www.frla.org/board-meetings/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1464-food-network-and-travel-channel-personalities-to-headline-florida-restaurant-and-lodging-associations-marketingoperations-summit https://www.frla.org/news-release/food-network-and-travel-channel-personalities-to-headline-florida-restaurant-and-lodging-associations-marketingoperations-summit/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1466--state-implements-new-food-service-inspection-frequency https://www.frla.org/news-release/state-implements-new-food-service-inspection-frequency/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1467-the-florida-restaurant-and-lodging-association-strengthens-efforts-in-palm-beach-by-welcoming-new-chapter-director- https://www.frla.org/news-release/the-florida-restaurant-and-lodging-association-strengthens-efforts-in-palm-beach-by-welcoming-new-chapter-director/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1468-hospitality-industry-executives-share-secrets-of-success-at-frlas-marketingoperations-summit https://www.frla.org/frla-news/item/1468-hospitality-industry-executives-share-secrets-of-success-at-frlas-marketingoperations-summit

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1472-frlas-regulatory-compliance-services-welcomes-new-northwest-florida-regional-manager https://www.frla.org/news-release/frlas-regulatory-compliance-services-welcomes-new-southeast-florida-regional-sales-manager/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1471-frla-endorses-governor-rick-scott-for-november-2014-election https://www.frla.org/news-release/frla-endorses-governor-rick-scott-for-november-2014-election/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1473-gov-scott-florida-tourism-on-pace-for-another-record-year- https://www.frla.org/news-release/gov-scott-florida-tourism-on-pace-for-another-record-year/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1474-endless-summer-music-series-brings-nashvilles-top-songwriters-to-destin-florida-for-free-concerts https://www.frla.org/news-release/endless-summer-music-series-brings-nashvilles-top-songwriters-to-destin-florida-for-free-concerts/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1486-frlas-tallahassee-chapter-installs-new-officers-and-board-of-directors-for-2015 https://www.frla.org/news-release/frlas-tallahassee-chapter-installs-new-officers-and-board-of-directors-for-2015/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1487-frlas-broward-chapter-installs-new-officers-and-board-of-directors-for-2015 https://www.frla.org/news-release/frlas-broward-chapter-installs-new-officers-and-board-of-directors-for-2015/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1485-frlas-palm-beach-chapter-installs-new-officers-and-board-of-directors-for-2015 https://www.frla.org/news-release/frlas-palm-beach-chapter-installs-new-officers-and-board-of-directors-for-2015/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1513-chef-emeril-lagasse-tours-family-owned-and-operated-restaurants-on-latest-episode-of-emerils-florida https://www.frla.org/news-release/chef-emeril-lagasse-tours-family-owned-and-operated-restaurants-on-latest-episode-of-emerils-florida-2/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1519-frlaef-announces-winners-of-hospitality-and-tourism-management-program-competition https://www.frla.org/news-release/frlaef-announces-winners-of-hospitality-and-tourism-management-program-competition/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1520-chef-emeril-lagasse-tours-kissimmee-on-latest-episode-of-emerils-florida https://www.frla.org/news-release/64807/

RedirectMatch 301 /educational-foundation/item/198-prostart-school-to-career-program https://www.frla.org/educational-foundation/prostart/

RedirectMatch 301 /educational-foundation/item/200-lodging-management-program https://www.frla.org/educational-foundation/htmpstart/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1529-member-spotlight-focus-on-guest-experiences-fuels-sustained-turnaround-at-steak-n-shake https://www.frla.org/news-release/member-spotlight-focus-on-guest-experiences-fuels-sustained-turnaround-at-steak-n-shake/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1530-nashvilles-top-songwriters-to-help-raise-money-for-childrens-charities-at-south-walton-beaches-wine-a-food-festival https://www.frla.org/news-release/nashvilles-top-songwriters-to-help-raise-money-for-childrens-charities-at-south-walton-beaches-wine-food-festival-2/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1532-more-than-150-songwriters-head-to-southernmost-point-for-20th-annual-festival-may-6-10-2015 https://www.frla.org/news-release/more-than-150-songwriters-head-to-southernmost-point-for-20th-annual-festival-may-6-10-2015/

RedirectMatch 301 /images/M_images/frla%202015%20legislative%20scorecard_updated.pdf https://www.frla.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/frla-2015-legislative-scorecard_updated1.pdf

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news/item/1537--tallahassee-restaurants-to-offer-fantastic-food-at-mouth-watering-prices-during-capital-cuisine-restaurant-week-and-concert-series-may-14-26 https://www.frla.org/news-release/release-1/

RedirectMatch 301 /frla-news https://www.frla.org/newsroom

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?uploads/wpjobboard/application/(.+) /wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/restrict.php?url=application/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You want to exclude a page or is it a directory? Also does it need to redirect to that?

Comment: I just want to exclude a single page.  Yeah, if it is accessed over https it needs to redirect to the http version.

Comment: Did you try my answer I provided?

Comment: Hi Panama Jack, I did try your solution but I got an endless loop error.  Do you know why that would be?

Comment: Are you replacing your current https to http rule with these? Clear you cache as well. What else do you have in your .htaccess file? Can you show how your are using this by pasting your current rules in the question.

Comment: I added the full code after your edits to my original question.  Let me know if I am missing anything that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thank you for all of your help.  I really appreciate it.  Just in case it helps anyone else I wanted to post the answer I came up with.

Instead of doing the redirect in the htaccess file I removed all of that code and setup my own Wordpress function in the functions.php file.  Also, in the Wordpress settings I set the Wordpress URL to be the https version (this controls how files are uploaded, which we need to be over https) but I set the Site URL to be the http version.  This is the function I wrote to handle the redirects...

```
function force_https () {
    $addr = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $production_site = true;

    if(preg_match('/localhost/', $addr) || preg_match('/developmentserver.com/', $addr)){
        $production_site = false;
    }

    //only redirect to SSL if it is on the production server.
    if($production_site == true){
        if ( !is_ssl() && !is_page('bill-tracker') ) {
        wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
        exit();
        }
        elseif (is_ssl() && is_page('bill-tracker')) {
            wp_redirect('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
            exit();
        }
    }
}

//only enable for production sites
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'force_https', 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule for your .htaccess. if you want to exclude `example-page` from https redirection. Replace your current rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^((?!example-page/?$).*)$ https://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^(example-page/?)$ http://frla.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```